# KML file with continents contours/borders

Tags: google-maps, gis, kml, google-earth

Do you have any idea where I could find kml file with simple contours of the continents?
I've been searching for it and all I've managed to find was KML that has more thatn 6MB. It contains too much details. I need something really simple. Just 7 continents. Nothing more.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "contours" do you mean "borders"?  A search for "countries" at [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables)  gave a number of results, including some [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) imports, such as this [1:110m simplified borders.](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=423734)

You can view a map of that table by clicking Visualize -> Map (zoom in a few levels to see the polygons).  From the map view you can click Export KML to download a KML.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful website. Great!